# How can I track Gnosis-Transactions?

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

How can I track the transaction done through Gnosis to know if it got successful or not ? Coz like any other wallet Gnosis returns different hash and it requires multiple signature to execute ...

Answer (score 0):

Your transactions can be tracked on-chain only when all signatures based on the owner threshold set are collected and one of the owners has executed a transaction. As long as it is not executed, you can't track it's status on blockchain explorers, as it's an off-chain interaction.